# C++ template integer types adequate unsigned type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and I've got such a method/function:

```
template<typename I>
void MyFunction(I &value)
{
    //some operations
    UI unsigned_type = static_cast<UI>(value);
}
```

Where the "I" is an integer type, and the "UI" should be an adequate usigned type. For example for 64bit integer type as the "I", the "UI" should be a 64bit unsigned integer type.

How can I do that?

Secondly, can I assure, that "I" will be always an integer type?

Thirdly I cannot use Boost ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement type traits for yourself. A library to use might be better but when you are not able to use on, you have to do it your own:

```
template<class T> 
struct make_unsigned; // no implementation

template<>
struct make_unsigned<int>
{
  typedef unsigned int type;
};

template<>
struct make_unsigned<unsigned int>
{
  typedef unsigned int type;
};

// and all other types you need ... (possibly implemented with help of a macro)
```

and in your code:

```
template<typename I>
void MyFunction(I &value)
{
    //some operations

    typedef make_unsigned<I>::type UI; 
    UI unsigned_type = static_cast<UI>(value);
}
```

Of course this is not perfect, but errors are manifested at compile time in your code and you can fix it.

*Edit:* 
If `I` is not an integer type (a type for which your specialisation exists) compilation will fail.

Comment: You need `make_unsigned`, not `make_signed`.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid in VS2005 you cannot do that straightforward (I don't think it supports C++11 to that extent). In C++11 you can use `std::is_signed< I >::value` to check if `I` is signed and `std::make_unsigned< I >::type` to get a corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: Yes, I could also easily check if it is an integer value. But VS2005 does not support C++11.

Comment: You can look at how `std::make_unsigned` is implemented in STL headers. Some type traits are not hard to implement, others  require SFINAE or compiler intrinsics.

Comment: Well, "you cannot do that" isn't really a correct answer then, is it?

Comment: @jrok I agree, the wording is wrong. It should be "cannot do that straightforward".

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use boost, you've got no choice but to implement some type-traits machinery yourself. It might be a bit tedious, but here's how you might go about it:

```
// convinience base classes
template<typename T, T Value>
struct constant { static const T value = Value; };

typedef constant<bool, true> true_type;
typedef constant<bool, false> false_type;

// a trait to check if two types are the same
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same : false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is_same<T,T> : true_type{};

// a trait to check if type is integral, based on is_same
// it's missing wchar_t and bool
#define SAME(T,U) is_same<T,U>::value
template<typename T>
struct is_integral : constant<bool,SAME(T,char) ||
                                   SAME(T,signed char) ||
                                   SAME(T,unsigned char) ||
                                   SAME(T,short) ||
                                   SAME(T,unsigned short) ||
                                   SAME(T,int) ||
                                   SAME(T,unsigned int) ||
                                   SAME(T,long) ||
                                   SAME(T,unsigned long) ||
                                   SAME(T,long long) ||
                                   SAME(T,unsigned long long)> {};

// Trait class to change a type to its unsigned variant.
// The base template simply forwards the type, specializations do the work.

template<typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
struct make_unsigned : identity<T> {};

template<> struct make_unsigned<signed char> : identity<unsigned char>{};
template<> struct make_unsigned<short>       : identity<unsigned short>{};
template<> struct make_unsigned<int>         : identity<unsigned int>{};
template<> struct make_unsigned<long>        : identity<unsigned long>{};
template<> struct make_unsigned<long long>   : identity<unsigned long long>{};

// Utility class to enable overloads based on some compile time condition
template<bool B, typename = void>
struct enable_if { };
template<typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    typedef T type;
};

// Only enable this function if I is integral
template<typename I>
typename enable_if<is_integral<I>::value>::type MyFunction(I &value)
{
    typename make_unsigned<I>::type ui;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    MyFunction(i); // ok
    float f;
    MyFunction(f); // fails
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer a lot. Hope you didn't mind. :-). +1 BTW.